# Run a batch file using a Windows 8 Metro Start Screen tile without switching to desktop

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

I was able to add a tile to the Windows 8 Metro Start Screen that, when touched, runs a batch file, following these instructions: [How to create shortcut of a file in Windows 8 Tiles?](https://superuser.com/questions/503256/how-to-create-shortcut-of-a-file-in-windows-8-tiles). The problem is that it switches to the desktop to run it. I would like that it runs in the background and stay in Metro mode. Is it possible?

EDIT:
I finally gave up and upgraded to Windows 10. In Windows 10 Tablet Mode, a batch file that is executed from the Start Screen will make all icons disappear during the time it executes, and once finished, icons appear again in a smoothly fashion.

Comment: Have you configured the batch file to run silently?

Comment: No, how do you suggest I do that?

Comment: I am not marking this as duplicate because I don't know if running the batch silently will prevent it from loading the desktop. But it is at least an avenue worth exploring I believe.

Comment: Please see these questions for methods to run batch or cmd silently: https://superuser.com/questions/191149/how-to-execute-cmd-exe-silently

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/596767/run-a-silent-batch-command-on-windows

Comment: I tried to change the shortcut target value to "start /b mybatch.bat" but since start is not an executable it won't accept it. I was able to run the batch file silently using this technique:(https://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-batch-file-in-a-completely-hidden-way) but it still loads the desktop.